# my html tags from my variable do not display in php

Tags: php, html, web-services, soap-client

I have this web service called to my curl file and the  response is in XML. now when i preview on my browse is doesn't display the Google map instead its displays the html tags.

```
$data= "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ser='http://services.webservices.vub.com/'>
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <ser:googlemap>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <address>ijzerenmolenstraat, leuven Belgium</address>
              </ser:googlemap>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>";
$url="http://localhost:8080/Venue_Finder_Soap_Version_/VenueFinder?WSDL";
$response=curl_soappost_call($url,$data);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo " </pre>";
```

output:
all the html tags

Comment: You do realize you are echoing the response inside pre tags, right?  Content inside the pre tag element are displayed as-is.

Comment: i know, even without it. i was just debugging. do you know i can display the html tags to yield response (my google map).this is the output i get:<div id='map-canvas' style='width: 500px; height: 300px'></div>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&key=AIzaSPrCZTUVSwdfl-yfpX47sxILSl-ngE8 &sensor=false"
    type="text/javascript"></script>    <style type="text/css">
       html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; }
        </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(
       ..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jquery to add the content to the DOM.  This way the new HTML, JS, and CSS will get properly rendered/executed.  Give the following a try:

**In the body section of your page:**

Place an empty div with a unique id attribute on your page where you want the content to appear,  such as:

```
 <div="the_google_map"></div>
```

**In the head section of your page:**

```
 // include the jquery library (Can be downloaded and hosted on your own server if desired)
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 $(document).ready(function(){  // don't run this code until the DOM is ready

    //  get the content  
    $data= "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ser='http://services.webservices.vub.com/'>
               <soapenv:Header/>
               <soapenv:Body>
                  <ser:googlemap>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <address>ijzerenmolenstraat, leuven Belgium</address>
                  </ser:googlemap>
               </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>";
    $url="http://localhost:8080/Venue_Finder_Soap_Version_/VenueFinder?WSDL";
    $response=curl_soappost_call($url,$data);

    // use jquery to insert the content into the DOM
    // Note the div id value here matches the div id used in the body
    $('#the_google_map').append($response);


 });
```